# Creating dynamic webpage that includes javascript POST action

Tags: javascript, python, html, rest, fetch

I am building a automation workflow (vRA) that includes a terms of service email.  If the customer wants a shared drive they must accept the TOS before the drive is automatically created.

The crux of the workflow is a *Custom Event* within vRO that waits on a POST request. This works with POSTMAN the problem I keep running into is the webpage link that will perform the POST.

I'm trying to create a webpage that will simply POST to this custom event, the page will have the Auth token embedded which will expire after 10 mins.

After finishing what I thought would be the difficult work I'm left scratching my head as one after another of my attempts to get this to work have failed.

```
def createwebpage(customevent, token):
   #Create javascript based webpage
   customevent = unicode(customevent, "utf-8")
   url = "https://automationserver/vco/api/customevent/" + customevent
   authtoken = "'Bearer ,Bearer " + token + "',"
   webpage = ("<html>\n" +
            "<head>\n" +
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
            "console.log(\"This is a test...\");\n" +
            "async function userAction() {\n" +
              "const URL = '" + url + "';\n"
              "fetchInit = {\n" +
                "method: 'POST',\n" +
                "mode: 'no-cors',\n" +
                "credentials: 'include',\n" +
                "body: '{\"executionId\": \"\",\"parameters\": [],\"profilerOptions\": {\"enabled\": true}',\n" +
                "headers: {\n" +
                    "'Content-Type': 'application/json',\n" +
                    "'Authorization': " + authtoken + "\n" +
                    "'cache-control': 'no-cache',\n" +
                    "'Accept': 'application/json'\n" +
                  "}\n" +
                "};\n" +
              "try {\n" +
                  "const fetchResult = fetch(\n" +
                  "new Request(URL, fetchInit));\n" +
                  "console.log(\"Completed request\");\n" +
                  "document.write(\"<b>Drive has been created...</b>\");\n" +
                "} catch (e) {\n" +
                "  throw Error(e);\n" +
                "}\n" +
              "};\n" +
          "</script>\n" +
        "</head>\n" +
          "<body>\n" +
              "<b>The shared drive located at CO - CO Test CANNOT be used to store - HIPPA / PCI information!!</b>\n" +
              "<br>\n" +
              "<b>By clicking Accept below you acknowledge no HIPPA / PCI information will be stored within the contents of files</b>\n" +
              "<br>\n" +
              "<br>\n" +
              "<form>\n" +
                "<button type=\"submit\" onclick=\"userAction()\">Accept</button>\n" +
              "</form>\n" +
            "</div>\n" +
          "</body>\n" +
        "</html>\n")
   #Write to file
   filename = '/tmp/web/' + customevent + ".html"
   with open(filename, 'w') as f:
      f.write(webpage)
```

The webpage this python code would generate is as follows.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("This is a test...");
async function userAction() {
const URL = 'https://automationserver/vco/api/customevent/58a4a5c2-160b-4d3f-bec9-7b7071cd6b0e';
fetchInit = {
method: 'POST',
mode: 'no-cors',
credentials: 'include',
body: '{"executionId": "","parameters": [],"profilerOptions": {"enabled": true}',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': 'token',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'Accept': 'application/json'
}
};
try {
const fetchResult = fetch(
new Request(URL, fetchInit));
console.log("Completed request");
document.write("<b>Drive has been created...</b>");
} catch (e) {
  throw Error(e);
}
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<b>The shared drive located at CO - CO Test CANNOT be used to store - HIPPA / PCI information!!</b>
<br>
<b>By clicking Accept below you acknowledge no HIPPA / PCI information will be stored within the contents of files</b>
<br>
<br>
<form>
<button type="submit" onclick="userAction()">Accept</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As a note I have already involved three systems in this automation workflow - I realize that the suggestion is to remove the no-cors and submit to proxy (why I don't know - it seems silly) but would like to avoid creating yet another dependency.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are incorrectly using the Fetch API.

I've rewritten the `userAction` function with what I believe would be working code. It's important to note that `fetch` will only throw an error if it encounters an error while making the HTTP request. If the response to that request is 400 or 500, it will handle the request as having been successful.

FYI, this code probably won't function on any version of Internet Explorer. So if you have users on IE, this won't work. You will need to use `XMLHttpRequest` or get a third party dependency via CDN to handle the network request for you.

```
function userAction() {
  const URL = 'https://automationserver/vco/api/customevent/58a4a5c2-160b-4d3f-bec9-7b7071cd6b0e';
  fetchInit = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: '{"executionId": "","parameters": [],"profilerOptions": {"enabled": true}',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'token',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  return fetch(URL, fetchInit)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("Completed request");
        document.write("<b>Drive has been created...</b>");
      } else {
        console.log('Non 200 response:');
        console.log(response.status, response.statusText);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Encountered error:');
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Dibble's answer got me most of the way there but I started getting the following error after including it in Firefox (worked in Chrome).

```
TypeError: NetworkError javascript fetch
```

This was resolved by removing form from the body of the HTML.  Someone more familiar with the intricacies of javascript maybe able to explain.

Final code that allowed POST.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function postData(url = ``, data = {}) {
  return fetch('https://automationserver/vco/api/customevent/event-code', {
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "no-cors",
  "cache": "no-cache",
  "credentials": "include", // include, *same-origin, omit
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": 'token-here',
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Accept": "application/json",
  },
  "redirect": "follow",
  "referrer": "no-referrer",
  "body": JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(response => response.json());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<b>The shared drive CANNOT be used to store - HIPPA / PCI information!!</b>
<br>
<b>By clicking Accept below you acknowledge no HIPPA / PCI information will be stored within the contents of files</b>
<br>
<br>
<button type="submit" onclick="postData()">Accept</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```